# Entity Framework - Include with multiple levels

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

If I have 3 classes A, B and C:

```
class A {
    public B b { get; set; }
    public C c { get; set; }
}

class B {
    public C c { get; set; }
}

class C {
    ...
}
```

When I make a query like:

```
Context.A.Where(...).Include(x => x.b).Include(x => x.c);
```

Entity loads the C object in both A and B, duplicating data. Is there a way to prevent it? I don't use lazy loading.

Comment: If you don't want C then why include it?  On the other hand, if C is literally the same object, then it's not duplicating data.

Comment: What do you get from simply using Context.A.Where(...) ?  What is that missing that you need to include?

Comment: i want c, i just dont want it twice. its coming duplicated on both objects, A and B.

Comment: And yes Erick, it's duplicating data. My response come with the full object C in both, A and B. Anyways, looks like nobody here can help me. These days people prefer to be ironic the help others here.

Answer (score 1):

You instruct Entity Framework to load the **b** and **c** entities with the **A** set. Since the **b** items contain references to items of type *C* that *might* be actually the same loaded items with the **a** objects, then Entity Framework will use them to construct the objects graph. That doesn't mean Entity Framework generates an extra SQL join to load the **c** items for the B type. To do this you would write

```
Context.A.Where(...).Include(x=>x.b).Include(x=>x.c).Include(x=>x.b.c)
```

Comment: In my opinion, with the query i made the correct is to load only a.b and a.c. If i wanted b.c i should write .Include(x => x.b.c). I'm not loading b.c but its coming filled, duplicating a lot of data.

Comment: It doesn't duplicate data. a.b.c and a.c reference to the same memory location.

Comment: well, my json response shoul contain only one object of type C. it's coming a lot bigger because of this. to me it's duplicating data :/